# Is 行く stative, continuous or instantaneous? 「今父はタバコを買いに行っています。」

Tags: grammar, aspect, verbs-of-motion

My textbook says 行く is instantaneous (expresses changes from one state to another) and can only be used to describe the result of a change, not movements that are currently in progress.  But a Japanese native has told me that it can be used to express an on-going action.  For example

> 今父はコンビニにタバコを買いに**行っています**。

describes the father somewhere in the process of the action.

So, as you can imagine, I'm very confused with all this.  Could somebody please clarify it a bit?  Is my textbook wrong?

Comment: Which textbook are you using?

Comment: Im using genki 1. It says 行っている cant be used as 'is going'

Comment: Related/Duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/53820/9831

Answer (score 8):

行っています doesn't express an on-going action in the same way that 走っている might be running. The sentence means that the father has gone to buy some fags and hasn't yet returned.

Answer (score 7):

Whether something is durative or instantaneous isn't a property of verbs, but of *predicates*:

- 「道を行く」 is durative
- 「うまく行く」 is durative (as @user4092 nicely pointed out)
- 「〇〇を買いに行く」 is instantaneous

With a **durative predicate**, you get these interpretations:

> **progressive**
>   仕事は（今）うまく行っている
>   "My job is going well (currently)."
>
> ｓｔａｔｅ
>     　　　　　　　　／　　　＼　　
>   **ーーーー｜｜｜｜｜｜｜？？？？？？？？？？＞**
>     　　　　＾　　　　　＾　　　　
>     　　ｂｅｇｉｎ　　ｎｏｗ
>     ｇｏｉｎｇ　ｗｅｌｌ
>
> **habitual**
>   仕事は（毎日）うまく行っている
>   "My job is going well (every day)."
>
> ＿＿＿＿＿＿＿ｓｔａｔｅ＿＿＿＿＿＿＿
>     ／　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　＼
>   **ーー｜｜ーー｜｜ーー｜｜ーー｜｜ーー｜｜ー＞**
>     　＼　　／＼　　／＼　　／＼　　／＼　　／
>     　　ｄ１　　ｄ２　　ｄ３　　ｄ４　　ｄ５
>   <sub>note: this habitual makes it explicit you are currently in the state of this action happening habitually, while the plain-form habitual does not make that explicit</sub>
>
> **perfective**
>   仕事は（今までに二回）うまく行っている
>   "My job has gone well (twice up to this point)."
>
> ＿＿＿＿＿＿＿ｓｔａｔｅ＿＿＿＿＿＿＿
>     ／　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　＼
>   **ーー｜｜｜ー｜｜｜ーー？？？？？？？？？？＞**
>     　　＼　／　＼　／　＾
>     　　　１　　　２　ｎｏｗ

With an **instantaneous predicate**, you get these interpretations:

> **resultative**
>   父は（今）タバコを買いに行っている
>   "My father is out to buy cigarettes (currently)."
>
> ｓｔａｔｅ
>     　　　　　　　　／　　　＼　　
>   **ーーーーｘ｜｜｜｜｜｜？？？？？？？？？？＞**
>     　　　　＾　　　　　＾　　
>     　ｇｏ　ｏｕｔ　　ｎｏｗ
>
> **habitual**
>   父は（毎日）タバコを買いに行っている
>   "My father is going out to buy cigarettes (every day)."
>
> ＿＿＿＿＿＿＿ｓｔａｔｅ＿＿＿＿＿＿＿
>     ／　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　＼
>   **ーーｘ｜ーーｘ｜ーーｘ｜ーーｘ｜ーーｘ｜ー＞**
>     　＼　　／＼　　／＼　　／＼　　／＼　　／
>     　　ｄ１　　ｄ２　　ｄ３　　ｄ４　　ｄ５
>
> **perfective**
>   父は（今までに二回）タバコを買いに行っている
>   "My father has gone out to buy cigarettes (twice up to this point)."
>
> ＿＿＿＿＿＿＿ｓｔａｔｅ＿＿＿＿＿＿＿
>     ／　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　＼
>   **ーーｘ｜｜ーｘ｜｜ーー？？？？？？？？？？＞**
>     　　＼　／　＼　／　＾
>     　　　１　　　２　ｎｏｗ

Generally, people explain that the difference between durative and instantaneous predicates is that a durative predicate gets a progressive interpretation (in addition to the other two), while an instantaneous predicate gets a resultative interpretation (in addition to the other two).

I agree with that explanation, but I hope by comparing the pictures of "progressive" and "resultative", you can see how they are pretty much exactly the same concept, it's just that it's the action which is continuing in the "progressive" case, while it's the result continuing in the "resultative" case.

## Your question

Your question really has to do with what that native speaker meant. The fact is that 「タバコを買いに行く」 is instantaneous and 「父は今タバコを買いに行っている」 has a "resultative" interpretation.

One possibility is that your native speaker source could have been saying that 「父は今タバコを買いに行っている」 can have the implication 「父は今タバコを買っている」, which is an action 父 is in the process of doing (though not necessarily -- while he went out to shop, he may instead be stuck in traffic or lost).

Another possibility is that your source did not properly convey what they meant, and they were only try to say what the "resultative" picture (and "progressive" picture, in fact) says, namely that the subject is in some on-going state.

Comment: +1 for awesome charts (and awesome explanation)

Comment: I don't think the charts are lining up properly for me.  Is there any chance you'd consider making them into images?

Answer (score 1):

行っている often means "he has been there" but that doesn't mean you always can't interpret it as "he is going". So, the textbook is wrong in that aspect.

1. [habitual action] ここのところ医者に行っている: I'm going to the doctor these days
2. [on-going action] うまく行っている: It's going well

Edit: When you find your father walking the street and you assume 「おっ、タバコ買いに行ってるな」, that 行っている is <s>the durative meaning</s> the on-going meaning.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jQn0ytqSm4#t=0m07s
 #13 and #5 in the blue shirt pressing the DF is what I'd yell 「行ってる！」.

Comment: Can you give some examples where 行っている means "he is going"?

Comment: (1. habitual action) ここのところ医者に行っている: I'm going to the doctor these days (2. on-going action) うまく行っている: It's going well

Comment: "that 行っている is the durative meaning". Are you sure about this? To me, he (1) タバコ買いに行った, and (2) is still in the resulting state of タバコ買いに行ってる, which is why you can say that sentence in that context. I think the line is not super clear, but since タバコ買いに行く at least sometimes instantaneous, and as far as I can tell, can always be correctly interpreted as instantaneous (as in this case), I would lean towards it always being instantaneous rather than complicating things.

Comment: Perhaps a useful test here is 〜ところだ. To me, タバコを買いに行ってるところだ could not possibly refer to what someone is doing while they are buying cigarettes, but instead must refer that they are just about to go -- this suggests to me that it's instantaneous. What do you think?

Comment: @user4092 How come you didn't add to your answer the examples you gave in your comment?

Comment: @Darius: Is 行く that severely instantenious?

Comment: @user4092 Well, I don't know. To me it is about changing state from "not gone" to "gone", but I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: I think you can regard any verbs as durative if you dare to, even if it's typical instanteneous 死ぬ. Compared with that, 行く is nothing. From an different angle, when 死んでいく is durative and 死んでいってる is an on-going action, how do we express something like 行っていく? We have to say 行く. Then 行っている is an on-going action.

Comment: @user4092 I think you're right. I've found some papers suggesting that things are indeed more complicated than I was hoping they'd be. http://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2433/87817/1/kgn00021_187.pdf#page=17

Comment: Thanks, that article was interesting and contained something new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Cited sentence obviously states a continuous state of his/her father being out and absent. In this case continual ています is indispensable, you can never say 今父はコンビニにタバコを買いに行きます.

In instantaneous sense, like "Tomorrow my father will go to the convenience store to buy cigarettes" (though this expample sounds pretty unreal), you can say 明日父はコンビニにタバコを買いに行きます.

So, roughly, 行きます is instantaneous and 行っています is continuous. Please learn about the continual ている/ています.
Here are my try of showing some continous examples similar to your one:

- 父は出ています。  My father is out now.
- 彼は入院しています。  He is in the hospital.
- 田中さんは田舎に帰っています。  Tanaka-san is back in his/her hometown.

Compare these with instantaneous 出ます, 入院します, 帰ります.

Comment: When I say instantaneous, I'm talking of the 3 verb types to consider when using ~ている: stative (continuous states), continuous (activities that last for some time) and instantaneous (changes that are more or less instantaneous).

Textbook says, and I quote, '行く indicates the current state that results from prior movements, NOT movements that are currently in progress.'

Comment: @Daniel Right. He has already gone out: it is the "going" which was the instantaneous action that 行って describes, and the being gone to buy X which is the continuous state after that which います describes. However, your textbook at some point explains that even supposedly "instantaneous" verbs aren't really. You *can* talk about the middle of the action, but it's normally so short that not a lot can happen between when it starts and when it ends.